# Java program error in uploading file throught PHP on Windows 7

Tags: java, php, file-upload, windows-7

I have a Java program that I made. It works fine on Windows XP, Windows 8 and Windows 10. But on Windows 7 I get error when I try to make it upload a txt file. Worst, the program on Win 7 uploads the file beautifully when I execute it inside the IDE (BlueJ) and it doesn't when I execute it normally, outside the IDE.
I have this code in PHP on website that stores the uploaded file (`upload.php`):

```
<?php 
$target_path = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 
} else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}
?>
```

The error shouldn't be from the php on the server side but I put it anyway.
Here is the java code for the uploading:

```
public void uploadRecordes()
    {
        final String ficRecordes = "recordes.txt";
        final String siteURL = "http://example.com/"
        final String CrLf = "\r\n";
        URLConnection conn = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(siteURL + "upload.php");
            //System.out.println("url:" + url);
            conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            String postData = "";

            InputStream imgIs = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + ficRecordes);
            byte[] imgData = new byte[imgIs.available()];
            imgIs.read(imgData);
            imgIs.close();

            String message1 = "";
            message1 += "-----------------------------4664151417711" + CrLf;
            message1 += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"" +
            ficRecordes + "\"" + CrLf;
            message1 += "Content-Type: text/txt" + CrLf;
            message1 += CrLf;

            // the image is sent between the messages in the multipart message.

            String message2 = "";
            message2 += CrLf + "-----------------------------4664151417711--"
                    + CrLf;

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4664151417711");
            // might not need to specify the content-length when sending chunked
            // data.
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf((message1
                    .length() + message2.length() + imgData.length)));

            //System.out.println("open os");
            os = conn.getOutputStream();

            //System.out.println(message1);
            os.write(message1.getBytes());

            // SEND THE IMAGE
            int index = 0;
            int size = 1024;
            do {
                //System.out.println("write:" + index);
                if ((index + size) > imgData.length) {
                    size = imgData.length - index;
                }
                os.write(imgData, index, size);
                index += size;
            } while (index < imgData.length);
            //System.out.println("written:" + index);

            //System.out.println(message2);
            os.write(message2.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            //System.out.println("open is");
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            char buff = 512;
            int len;
            byte[] data = new byte[buff];
            do {
                //System.out.println("READ");
                len = is.read(data);

                if (len > 0) {
                    //System.out.println(new String(data, 0, len));
                }
            } while (len > 0);

            //System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //System.out.println("Close connection");
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

The error that it gives me on Win 7 is `NullPointerException`.
And it appears `at Game.uploadRecordes(Game.java:149)`. This means that the error is on line 149? If so, the line is

```
byte[] imgData = new byte[imgIs.available()];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
InputStream imgIs = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + ficRecordes);
```

with

```
FileInputStream imgIs = new FileInputStream(new File(ficRecordes));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that previous line

```
InputStream imgIs = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + ficRecordes);
```

It seems like getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + ficRecordes); is returning a null reference. There are plenty of answers on stackoverflow related to this command. Try searching for an answer there.

Comment: I have tried a lot of new approaches but nothing works. The problem is that this error doesn't appear when executing inside the IDE

Comment: Because the IDE sets classpaths differently than the vm would do normally.
Is the recordes.txt inside the jar or somewhere else?
Try to store the recordes.txt in C:/ and then say `InputStream imgIs = new File("C:/recordes.txt").getInputStream();` and try again

Comment: thank you. I already made it work with `FileInputStream imgIs = new FileInputStream(new File(ficRecordes));`